# Swift: Cannot assign value of type 'String.CharacterView.index' to type 'Int'

Tags: swift

Does anyone know why I get the following error when I run my code below?

Error: Cannot assign value of type 'String.CharacterView.index' to type 'Int'

```
var problem = "find the longest word in the problem description"
var last = problem.characters.last
let lastIndex = problem.characters.endIndex;
print(last);
var words:[String] = [String]();
var word:String = "";
var lastCheck:Int = 0;
for i in problem.characters{
    lastCheck = lastCheck + 1
    if i != " "{
        word = word + String(i)
    }
    else if lastCheck = lastIndex{
        words.append(word);
    }
    else if i == " "{
        words.append(word)
        word = ""
    }
}
print(words)
```

***UPDATE***

I have tried changing the let lastIndex to var lastIndex but no luck

Comment: `var last = problem.characters.last` . How can you use the variable in its own scope?

Comment: @Dershowitz123 It's not the same object. There's the property on characters and there's OP's variable: two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare `lastCheck` (an `Int`) and `lastIndex` (an `Index`).

You have to convert it:

```
var problem = "find the longest word in the problem description"
var last = problem.characters.last
let lastIndex = problem.characters.endIndex;
print(last);
var words:[String] = [String]();
var word:String = "";
var lastCheck:Int = 0;
for i in problem.characters{
    lastCheck = lastCheck + 1
    let lastIndexInt = problem.characters.startIndex.distanceTo(end: lastIndex) // new
    if i != " "{
        word = word + String(i)
    }
    else if lastCheck = lastIndex{
        words.append(word);
    }
    else if i == " "{
        words.append(word)
        word = ""
    }
}
print(words)
```

Comment: Index isn't an Int? This is what I learned in other languages

Comment: No, because it doesn't make sense to access unicode extended grapheme clusters by a regular index. Some bytes represent modifiers to characters, and not characters themselves. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID293

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler solution to your problem:

```
let input = "find the longest word in the problem description";

let longest = input
    .characters //get the input characters
    .split(separator:" ", //split by spaces
           maxSplits: 1000, //max number of splits
           omittingEmptySubsequences: true) //omit "" splits
    .map(String.init) //make new strings from the characters
    .max{$0.characters.count < $1.characters.count} //get longest length word

print(longest)
```

Thanks to [originaluser2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2976878/originaluser2)

Comment: Or just `let longestWord = input.components(separatedBy: " ").max{$0.characters.count < $1.characters.count}` ;) (`componentsSeparatedByString` + `maxElement` for Swift 2)

Comment: I was tryign to avoid using foundation, but that max function is cool!

Answer (score 0):

`String.CharacterView.Index` is a `struct` but not `Int`. So you cannot assign a `Int` to your `String.CharacterView.Index` variable. It's normal.

You have to convert to Int as @Amomchilov's answer, or use Index :

```
...
var lastCheck:String.CharacterView.Index = problem.startIndex
for i in problem.characters {
    lastCheck = lastCheck.advancedBy(1)
    ...
}
```

Anyway, in order to find the longest word of a phrase, you can use builtIn function of Swift to get all words then compare their length.
For example:

```
let str = "find the longest word in the problem description"
var longestWord : String?
str.enumerateSubstringsInRange(str.startIndex..<str.endIndex, options:.ByWords) {
    (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, value) in
    if let _subString = substring {
        if longestWord == nil  || longestWord!.characters.count < _subString.characters.count {
            longestWord = _subString
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to get all the words in sentence

```
var problem = "find the longest word in the problem description"
problem.enumerateSubstrings(in: (problem.range(of: problem))!, options: NSString.EnumerationOptions.byWords, { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in

print(substring)
})
```

Easy way to get longest word in sentence

```
var longestWord = ""
problem.enumerateSubstrings(in: (problem.range(of: problem))!, options: NSString.EnumerationOptions.byWords, { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in
if longestWord.characters.count < substring?.characters.count{
    longestWord = substring!
}
})
print(longestWord)
```

Note:Code with reference to Swift 3.For lower version of there will be some syntax changes.Let me know if you need the same for lower versions.